# iMessage deleted by the other iphone removes it from my thread on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

If someone I am iMessaging with on the iPhone-4S sends me a message and they delete it; will it also delete on my phone??

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **No.**

As long as you are on two separate phones (not using the same Messages app on one phone - practically impossible, theoretically possible), it will stay entirely separate from your Messages thread.